# GSuite: Difference between Managing API client access and Whitelisting connected apps

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I want to enable an application developed by third-party using admin console. I find two options which do want I am looking for. Two options are "[Managing API client acces](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)s" and "[Whitelisting connected apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en)". But I am unable to understand the difference between the two.

"**connected apps**" mean server to server communication without explicit user login?

Kiran

Comment: As per your description of what you're trying to do, it falls under [Whitelisting connected apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en) as you want to "enable" (whitelist) a third-party app. For that, follow the steps indicated in the link.

Comment: @noogui Thanks for reply. I want to know the difference between the two. Can you provide more details?